# How can i replace Spaces in the keys in JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON as following

```
var suppResJSon = [
  {
    "Name": "_Astec_Lifesciences_Ltd",
    "Sector": "PHARMACEUTICALS",
    "Current Price": 349.05,
    "Pivot Point": 348.93333333333334,
    "Resistance 1": 352.8666666666667,
    "Resistance 2": 356.68333333333334,
    "Resistance 3": 360.6166666666667,
    "Support 1": 345.1166666666667,
    "Support 2": 341.18333333333334,
    "Support 3": 337.3666666666667
  },
  {
    "Name": "_Gujarat_Gas_Co_Ltd",
    "Sector": "GAS",
    "Current Price": 177.85,
    "Pivot Point": 177.20000000000002,
    "Resistance 1": 179.25000000000003,
    "Resistance 2": 180.65,
    "Resistance 3": 182.70000000000002,
    "Support 1": 175.80000000000004,
    "Support 2": 173.75000000000003,
    "Support 3": 172.35000000000005
  }
  ]
```

How can i replace **Spaces** in the keys for example

```
 Support 1 with Support1



 Support 2 with Support2



 Support 3 with Support3
```

I have tried as following

```
 suppResJSon = suppResJSon.replace('Support 1', 'Support1');
   suppResJSon = suppResJSon.replace('Support 2', 'Support2');
    suppResJSon = suppResJSon.replace('Support 3', 'Support3');

console.log(suppResJSon)
```

but getting following exception

```
(index):125 Uncaught TypeError: suppResJSon.replace is not a function
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1gk68zjh/

Answer (score 2):

Using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to dynamically replace spaces with nothing in your keys.

```js
const data=[{Name:"_Astec_Lifesciences_Ltd",Sector:"PHARMACEUTICALS","Current Price":349.05,"Pivot Point":348.93333333333334,"Resistance 1":352.8666666666667,"Resistance 2":356.68333333333334,"Resistance 3":360.6166666666667,"Support 1":345.1166666666667,"Support 2":341.18333333333334,"Support 3":337.3666666666667},{Name:"_Gujarat_Gas_Co_Ltd",Sector:"GAS","Current Price":177.85,"Pivot Point":177.20000000000002,"Resistance 1":179.25000000000003,"Resistance 2":180.65,"Resistance 3":182.70000000000002,"Support 1":175.80000000000004,"Support 2":173.75000000000003,"Support 3":172.35000000000005}];

const res = data.map(item=>{
  return Object
    .entries(item)
    .reduce((acc,[key,value])=>{
      return {[key.replace(/\s/g, '')]:value, ...acc};
    }, {});
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple, just iterate over the object keys, copy the value to a new key, and remove the old key.

```js
var suppResJSon = [{
  "Name": "_Astec_Lifesciences_Ltd",
  "Sector": "PHARMACEUTICALS",
  "Current Price": 349.05,
  "Pivot Point": 348.93333333333334,
  "Resistance 1": 352.8666666666667,
  "Resistance 2": 356.68333333333334,
  "Resistance 3": 360.6166666666667,
  "Support 1": 345.1166666666667,
  "Support 2": 341.18333333333334,
  "Support 3": 337.3666666666667
}, {
  "Name": "_Gujarat_Gas_Co_Ltd",
  "Sector": "GAS",
  "Current Price": 177.85,
  "Pivot Point": 177.20000000000002,
  "Resistance 1": 179.25000000000003,
  "Resistance 2": 180.65,
  "Resistance 3": 182.70000000000002,
  "Support 1": 175.80000000000004,
  "Support 2": 173.75000000000003,
  "Support 3": 172.35000000000005
}];

console.log(fixKeys(suppResJSon));

function fixKeys(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(item => fixKeys(item));
  } else {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      if (key.match(/\s+/g)) {
        let newKey = key.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        obj[newKey] = obj[key];
        delete obj[key];
      }
    });
  }
  return obj;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this with a `map` and `reduce`:

```js
var suppResJSon = [{
    "Name": "_Astec_Lifesciences_Ltd",
    "Sector": "PHARMACEUTICALS",
    "Current Price": 349.05,
    "Pivot Point": 348.93333333333334,
    "Resistance 1": 352.8666666666667,
    "Resistance 2": 356.68333333333334,
    "Resistance 3": 360.6166666666667,
    "Support 1": 345.1166666666667,
    "Support 2": 341.18333333333334,
    "Support 3": 337.3666666666667
},
    {
        "Name": "_Gujarat_Gas_Co_Ltd",
        "Sector": "GAS",
        "Current Price": 177.85,
        "Pivot Point": 177.20000000000002,
        "Resistance 1": 179.25000000000003,
        "Resistance 2": 180.65,
        "Resistance 3": 182.70000000000002,
        "Support 1": 175.80000000000004,
        "Support 2": 173.75000000000003,
        "Support 3": 172.35000000000005
    }
];

const result = suppResJSon.map(v =>
    Object.entries(v).reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>
        Object.assign(acc, {[key.replace(/\s+/g, '_')]: value}),
        {}));

console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps,